# How to sample native resolution texture in glsl fragment shader

Tags: textures, glsl, multisampling

I am trying to use a 2d texture as a lookup table to index into a larger texture.  Then texture map the color value onto a quad.  The issue I am having is that the larger texture appears to be smaller then its native resolution, when I sample it.  For example, I have a large 4k x 4k texture.  The lookup texture samples a 1k x 1k region of the large texture.  It then texture maps the result to a quad that fills the viewport, which is also 1k wide x 1k high.  I expect to still see a 1:1 map between the textured quad and a 1k x 1k portion of the original 4k x 4k texture.  However, the textured quad is very aliased.  It appears as if though the 4k x 4k texture was reduced to a 1k x 1k texture, and my lookup map samples a 512 x 512 portion of that texture.

In another word, it appears as if though I am sampling from a texture that has been resized to fit the 1k x 1k viewport, and not the native 4k x 4k texture.  Is there an issue with the why I am approaching this problem?

Here is my vertex shader:

```
uniform mat4 pvm;

void main()
{   
    gl_TexCoord[0] = gl_MultiTexCoord0;
    gl_Position = ftransform();
}

and fragment shader:

uniform sampler2D image;  //The large texture
uniform sampler2D map;    //The lookup texture

void main()
{

    vec4 pos = texture(map,(gl_TexCoord[0].st * vec2(-1.0, 1.0)));  //Flip the origin

    vec4 color = texelFetch(image,ivec2(pos.s*4096,pos.t*4096),0);  
    gl_FragColor = color;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not surprising that aliasing is a noticable issue, `texelFetch (...)` disables filtering, including mip mapping. You will have to implement this stuff yourself if you use this function.

A typical use case for `texelFetch (...)` is to disable texture filtering (*not what you want here*) or to fetch a specific sample from a multisample texture (*also not what you want*). You would be better off using normalized texture coordinates and a regular `texture (...)` if you want texture anti-aliasing.

Comment: Hi Andon, I have also tried to simply use: 
vec4 color = texture(image,vec2(pos.s,pos.t)); instead of texelfetch.
The result is identical to the texelFetch.

Comment: @user2964105: What is your texture filter for the textures you have bound to the `map` and `image` samplers? If map's filter is nearest neighbor, then this is to be expected because instead of interpolating coordinates you are selecting the nearest integer coordinate. I cannot say for certain, but I imagine you want a smooth transition between adjacent texels instead of an abrupt snap-to-grid behavior. If you use a linear min/mag filter for both textures, you should get ***much*** less aliasing. In fact, the texture filter of your `map` texture is more important here than the filter of `image`

Comment: @user2964105: It all comes down to how the texture coordinates are generated. Normally if you were not using a lookup texture to find the coordinates they would be smoothly interpolated across your polygon, but since your coordinates are dependent upon a fetch from another texture, the behavior is dependent on your texture filter.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I believe I have located the issue.  The program was because I used a GL_BYTE size for each color in the lookup texture.  This did not give me a fine enough granularity to fetch from the large texture.  After I switched to GL_Float, the issue went away.